# Haskell Error in swaping list elements

Tags: list, haskell

does anyone know why this still gives me error?

```
main = do
print $ check [4,3,2] 0 1 
-- output expected [3,4,2], means just once check and swap not more

check ( modXs, []) _ _  = modXs
check ( modXs, [x]) _ _ = x : modXs
check ( modXs, (x1:x2:xs)) counter limit 
    | x1 > x2 && counter < limit =  x2:check (x1 : xs)  (counter+1) limit
    | otherwise = x1 : check (x2 : xs) counter limit
```

the error message here says something about type I dont  even understand it :

```
Couldn't match expected type `([a1], [a1])' with actual type `[a1]'
    In the first argument of `check', namely `(x1 : xs)'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely
      `check (x1 : xs) (counter + 1) limit'
    In the expression: x2 : check (x1 : xs) (counter + 1) limit
```

Comment: Could you also post your error?  And could you include the type signature for `check`?

Comment: Looks like you're calling check with the wrong arguments in `main`. Its first arg is a tuple and you're passing just a list. Also, it looks like check is pure, so perhaps you meant `main = print $ check (something, [4,3,2]) 0 1`?

Comment: Thats true thanks but still same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check` expects to be handed a tuple as its first arguments; so all calls to it -- both in `main` and in the body of `check` itself -- must pass it a tuple.